# Algebraic geometry book with numerical examples

Tags: algebraic-geometry, real-algebraic-geometry

There are questions asked earlier on this topic but I find that most of these books have proofs mostly. I am from software background but I can understand it if I get a sufficiently simple book containing numerous numerical examples.

Some book that patiently explains everything with simple numerical examples like say ideals on [this page](http://www.millersville.edu/~bikenaga/abstract-algebra-1/ideal/ideal.html).

I am also aware of computational books on this topic. Tell me the simplest book with simplest examples.

Comment: Maybe http://www.springer.com/cn/book/9781441922571 ? It should be kind of basic and keep an eye towards applications.

Comment: @MattiaTalpo : I know it, it needs one to be aware of basics.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/830859/reference-request-algebraic-methods-in-geometry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides this book mentioned in the comments

- [Ideals, Varieties, and Algorithms](http://www.springer.com/cn/book/9781441922571)

try

- [Computing in Algebraic Geometry: A Quick Start using SINGULAR](http://www.springer.com/br/book/9783540289920)
- [A First Course in Computational Algebraic Geometry](http://www.us.cambridge.org/aus/catalogue/catalogue.asp?isbn=9781107612532)
- [Computations in algebraic geometry with Macaulay 2](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/Macaulay2/Book/)

and also

- [A Singular Introduction to Commutative Algebra](https://www.singular.uni-kl.de/Singular-book.html)